# IMAP parser or server examples

Tags: parsing, email, go, imap

I've been assigned to build an IMAP server with Go, and after a bit of research I figured I'll have to build it all by myself, so before I do anything I want to know what you guys think. I need some IMAP parser or a server example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [cyrus-imapd](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/) or [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

IMAP is a [simple textual protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) which is *very* similar to [SMTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) in this regard, so check out how [`net/smtp`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/) is implemented.

And server-side IMAP implementation differ from client side only in that it most of the time responds to commands, not initiate them, so check out [existing client implementation](https://github.com/emersion/go-imap).

Comment: IMAP is not so simple: commands can be interwoven, with responses for multiple commands intermixed, based upon the tags, and untagged messages be sent by the server at any time, providing status updates. You'll need to support this in a new server to handle things like the `IDLE` command. Treating IMAP as a lockstep protocol like SMTP is a recipe for disaster. You need a full state-machine instead.

Comment: @PhilP, it's supposed the OP will RTFM, isn't it? The question was about parser and I have equipped them with the concrete examples on how to approach parsing IMAP procotol commands.

Comment: No, since SMTP is line-based while IMAP commands include synchronising and non-synchronising literals, so it's not even the same at that level.  The only similarity comes from "use bufio"; everything after that is different.